# Moving from C# to C++ (plus working with both in same solution)

Tags: c#, c++

This is a very general question.  I'm a self taught 'programmer' who programs in C#.  A project I would like to work on would be made a whole lot easier (in the grand scheme of things) if I knew C++.  How easy is it to move from C# to C++?  Any pitfalls I should watch out for?   And if I am using VS2010, can I program (not in the same class, but same project) something in both C# and C++?

Comment: It's easier to [shoot yourself into the foot in C++](http://m5p.com/~pravn/foot.html) and it will hurt you much more than in C#.

Comment: @UweKeim This is hilarious, I had a really good laugh! Thank you!

Comment: @keynesiancross I am sorry to say that you have some **really** tough days ahead ahahahahaah

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Moving from C# to C++ is not easy. The basic syntax can appear the same (e.g. if, for...), but there are *deep differences*, e.g. the RAII pattern and stack-semantics variables whose destructors are called when they go out of scope, etc. are not present in C#.

Moreover, C# uses a non-deterministic garbage collector (which can be OK for memory resources, but is useless for other kind of resources). Instead, with modern C++, you can use templates and smart pointers (like std::/boost::*shared_ptr*), which allow you to have *deterministic* reference-counted "garbage collection", which is very efficient, and is valid for both memory and non-memory resources (like file handles, sockets, textures...).

Moreover, the C# generics are very different from C++ templates (C++ templates are *very* powerful, and allow an advanced level of programming called *template meta-programming*).

In VS2010 you can have a solution hosting both C++ and C# projects. To communicate between the two worlds (the native world of C++ and the managed world of .NET/C#) you can use C++/CLI as a kind of bridging layer.

In Windows 8 a new technology should be introduced, called WinRT (based on COM), which allows inter-language communication. In this case, you can use C++ with WRL (a template-based library) or C++/CX language extensions to build C++ components that can be used from C# and .NET.

Happy learning.

Comment: Thanks for your solid response.  Now, admittedly, I have no idea what the first three things you talk about are... (RAII / stack sematics??, non-deterministic garbage collector?? and templates??)

Comment: If you mention `shared_ptr` you should at least also mention the obvious problems with it compared to a GC (cycles, multithreading, performance) otherwise that could lead to interesting surprises for the unaware. Minor note: ref counting efficient? No, not really.

Comment: @Voo: ref counting is certainly more efficient than having a garbage collector running as a background thread and at some point in time freezing everything walking memory marking and sweeping it. Moreover, I think .NET GC is run under memory pressure, but it has no clue about other resources (like sockets, or texture memory on graphics cards, etc.). Instead with C++ destructors and shared_ptr every resources (not only system memory) are released as soon as no one is referencing them anymore.

Comment: @keynesiancross: Thank you. Regarding RAII, you may want to consider the Wikipedia article. Basically, in C++ you may want to manage a raw resource wrapping it in a C++ class: the constructor of the class acquires the resource, the destructor releases it (this applies to every kind of resource, not only system memory). If you define instances of this class on the stack, as soon as the instance goes out of scope, the destructor is called, so the resource is released. This happens in a deterministic way. Thanks to destructors, you can write C++ code that is structurally incapable of leaking.

Comment: @keynesiancross: If the resource is shared between different owners, it is possible to wrap it using a shared_ptr, which basically manages the shared resource using reference counting, and as soon as the ref count reaches zero (i.e. no one is referencing the resource anymore) it is released (i.e. the destructor is called). Again, this is a deterministic process (ref count == 0 --> the resource is released). Templates are a way of expressing generic code (e.g.: a container of "T", where T can be a string, an integer, a structure, a custom class...).

Comment: @Mr_C64 If you don't understand why ref counting is basically the least efficient way to implement any kind of resource sharing I doubt a 500character will offer enough space to explain all the reasons for this. Sufficient to say ref counting GC (which basically amounts to the same as shared_ptrs) is used in no modern GC algorithm because of its overhead, bad scalability and problems with cycles. And yes using a GC to handle resources other than memory is a bad idea - who argued about that point?

Comment: @Voo: If you don't understand the benefits of a uniform approach (for both memory and non-memory resources) as C++'s destructors and shared_ptr offer, and the fact that in several cases there is no need for shared ownership, and scoped_ptr (for C++03) or unique_ptr (for C++11) can do just fine and in a very efficient way, I doubt a 500character will offer enough space to explain.

Answer (score 9):

I came the other way from c++ to c#. In many ways that was a relief. C++ has a lot more rules than c# particularly around memory allocation. The syntax can also be challenging and it is easy to wander off into out of bounds memory. C++ is however much more suitable for system level programming but *with great power comes great responsibility*.

I recommend first grabbing a copy of Scott Meyer's [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) and read it cover to cover. This is the best resource I know of for getting the basics correct and without question improved the quality of the code I was producing, even as an "experienced" c++ developer. Then grab a unit test framework and take a look at a [c++ kata](http://vimeo.com/8446999) (in this case an xcode project but should still be useful). And get familiar with the [Standard Template Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) which contains a lot of useful/efficient code/classes for containers, algorithms, etc.

Lastly, best of luck. Learning a new language is always a challenge and can be daunting but the payoff is generally worth it. If nothing else you will see your c# code with new eyes.

Answer (score 5):

> can I program (not in the same class, but same project) something in both C# 
>       and C++?

Answer is no you cannot. You can if you use Managed C++ & C++. But if you are working with C# then you can't have C# and C++ code inside same project

> How easy is it to move from C# to C++?`

It is a bit subjective but in my opinion it will be a very hard step. C++ is a different language so it will be as hard as learning a new language :) again it's subjective so I won't go into details

Answer (score 5):

Since you're working with .NET, I presume you're using Visual Studio?

It's rather easy to combine C# and C++ in the same program, using the `/clr` compiler option.  Your C++ code can include both normal, standard-compliant C++ classes, and also `ref class` .NET objects designed for use from C#.  The two are separate but can access each other, via pointers from `ref class` to native `class`, and the `gcroot` template from native `class` to `ref class`.

Note that I said "in the same *program*", not "in the same *project*".  You'll have to split into two parts, one C# project and one C++/CLI project, and one will be a DLL that the other loads.  There's also a trick for combining the two together during build so you end up with a single executable file, but that's more trouble than it's usually worth.

---

Note, you might find this smart pointer class I wrote useful, it makes the use of native `class` objects from `ref class` .NET objects much easier.

- [`scoped_ptr` for C++/CLI (ensure managed object properly frees owned native object)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/scoped-ptr-for-c-cli-ensure-managed-object-properly-frees-owned-native-object)